# Effect of a external EM field on a dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, non-linear-optics

If an external EM field (a laser, for example) act on a dielectric (a glass, for example) what will be the effect of this field on the dielectric constant and on the refractive index of the material? How, mathematically speaking, could I explain what is happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linear electrodynamics (i.e. low intensities), the dielectric constant and refractive index remain unchanged. A different thing is [nonlinear optics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics) (applying to ED in general as well), for more theory see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics#Theory). But this happens only for materials with strong non-linear parameters (usually $\chi^{(2)}$ or $\chi^{(3)}$) and for rather high field intensities. This usually yields effect such as the [second harmonic generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_harmonic_generation), but there is also the effect of [self-focusing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-focusing) among others, which stems from the dependence of the refractive index on the field amplitude.

Comment: Thank you so so much! That is exactly what I looking for!